# Get selected checkbox without Name or Xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to get the selected Checkbox from list of checkboxes without name or xpath

Checkbox Image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg1As.png)

> HTML Code generated

```
<div class="checkbox ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in options track by $index">
   <label class="ng-binding" style="float:left;">
<input type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-change="textfieldKeypress(onkeypress)" ng-model="$parent.inputArray[$index]" validator="[onwatch,onblur]" value="item" >
    Ache </label> 
</div>
```

This is what i had tried but was not the right way since there are multiple checkbox list without name

```
List<WebElement> CheckBoxList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("checkbox"));
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList.size(); i++) {
        if (CheckBoxList.get(i).isSelected()) {
            Assert.assertEquals("Ache", CheckBoxList.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried byModel: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model?

Comment: @maurycy I am using Selenium Webdriver. not protractor..

Comment: Why don't you want to use an xpath?

Comment: In your example all the check boxes are having a name, what exactly you want to show if a checkbox is not having a name.

Comment: I can not see any tag like "checkbox", your code should be `List<WebElement> CheckBoxList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));`

Comment: use css path then :D

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar can you please check code i had added checkbox tag

Comment: @Arun All checkbox tags are not having name so i want to find out how it can done since there are multiple checkbox list like shown above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the checkbox state cannot be evaluated with an XPath and that the text cannot be evaluate with a CSS selector, I would take the elements present in both :

```
// get the checked checkboxes
List<WebElement> m_checked = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:checked[type=checkbox]"));

// get the checkboxes matching the text
List<WebElement> m_text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.)='Ache']/input[@type='checkbox']"));

// get the checkboxes checked matching the text
Collection elements = CollectionUtils.retainAll(m_checked, m_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below `xpath = //div[@class='checkbox ng-scope']`

if you have morethan one checkbox then use below `xpath`

(//`div[@class='checkbox ng-scope']`)
[1] you change the value of 1 to 2/3/4 and so on.

Comment: div[@class='checkbox ng-scope'] will be manual process there  are more than 100 checkbox having same div

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `isSelected()` use `.getAttribute("checked")` and then compare the return with Boolean `true` in if clause.